# Preciso colocar 4 cards na mesma linha, estou usando: display: flex e flex-flow: row; mas eles ficam um abaixo do outro, alguem sabe o que fazer?

Tags: css

```css
.carrosel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.cards {
  width: 266px;
  height: 493px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -4px rgba;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="carrosel">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="imagecards">
      <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
      <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
      <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
      <button class="btncards">
        <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="imagecards">
        <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
        <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
        <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
        <button class="btncards">
          <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="imagecards">
          <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
          <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
          <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
          <button class="btncards">
            <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="imagecards">
            <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
            <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
            <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
            <button class="btncards">
              <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
            </button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava faltando fechar as tags `div` das classes "cards", então o segundo card estava dentro do primeiro, o terceiro dentro do segundo e assim por diante. Não havia como ficar lado a lado dentro do "carrosel", já que só havia efetivamente, um *card* dentro do *carrosel*.

Segue o abaixo o código com as alterações de fechamento de tags seguidas do comentário `<!-- ADICIONADA -->`

```css
.carrosel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.cards {
  width: 266px;
  height: 493px;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px -4px rgba;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="carrosel">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="imagecards">
      <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
      <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
      <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
      <button class="btncards">
        <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- ADICIONADA -->
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="imagecards">
      <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
      <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
      <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
      <button class="btncards">
        <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- ADICIONADA -->
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="imagecards">
      <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
      <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
      <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
      <button class="btncards">
        <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- ADICIONADA -->
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="imagecards">
      <img src="Mask group (2).png" alt="">
      <h2>Teste A/B</h2>
      <p>Um teste A/B consiste em comparar o desempenho de uma ou mais versões (variantes) de uma página em relação à original por meio da análise de métricas como taxa de conversão, funil de vendas, dados de tráfego, entre outros.</p>
      <button class="btncards">
        <a href='https://www.freecodecamp.org/'>Saiba mais</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- ADICIONADA -->
</div> <!-- ADICIONADA -->
```